# Search Ant Design Tree Select by Title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, ant-design-pro

By default Tree select of Ant design search by value, is there a way to search by title?
I have tried using `onSearch` function but it doesn't change any behavior of Tree Select

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can search by title, or any other fields of your treeData item, there is a callback prop filterTreeNode for that purpose

Example:

```
<TreeSelect
 treeData={data}
 filterTreeNode={(search, item) => {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      }}
/>
```

Answer (score 17):

Just to elaborate on the answer provided by @Oliver, you can add the following props:

```
<TreeSelect

  showSearch
  treeNodeFilterProp='title'
  treeData={treeData}
  ...

/>
```

You can use the `filterTreeNode` prop to provide a custom filter function, but for standard functionality it should not be needed.

Answer (score 5):

There's actually a better and simpler way to do it by providing `treeNodeFilterProp`, which is directly used for filtering. Its default value is 'value' and you can simply change it to 'title' to achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but you could simply use `treeNodeFilterProp` property of `TreeSelect`:

```
 <TreeSelect
  treeData={data}
  treeNodeFilterProp="title"
 />
```

So it'll search on `title`s.

The documentation is not good for this component...